# [Java][Spring-boot] @NotNull annotations not DDL

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, notnull

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G8Bt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imnKq.png)

https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-notnull-vs-nullable

I understand that @NotNull also adds ddl(not null),
but only @Column(nullable = false) has added ddl(not null).

I am using Java11 version.
I want to know why ddl cannot be added through @NotNull.
you tell me the reason Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@Column(name="EmployeeName" nullable=false) nullable indicates that name field or column in the table can not have a null value. You are saying that even after adding the annotation you are able to insert the null value to the column?

Comment: I want to Use @NotNull to add database in not null..

Comment: The @ NotNull Annotation is, actually, an explicit contract declaring the following:

A method should not return null.
A variable (like fields, local variables, and parameters) cannot should not hold null value. example :- 

public void setX(@ NotNull final Object aX ) {
    // some code
}

The @ NotNull annotation doesn't do any validation on its own because the annotation definition does not provide any ConstraintValidator type reference.

Comment: In the above site, if you add @NotNullAnnotation, 'not null' is added when you create a database through Hibernate, is that not possible?